# Damaged hard drive due to magnet damage (Macbook Pro)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive

I am able to get internet recovery on my Macbook Pro that I [previously wiped with a magnet](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/129570/5472)

I was trying to re-install OS X Mountain Lion again but when I got to the 'choose a disk' there was no 'disk' to be found.

I'm not too sure what this means, could someone please explain if this is something I can fix myself?

Comment: In Internet Recovery, if you open Disk Utility do you see a hard drive listed on the left hand side?  If so choose it, click erase, give the drive a name, click erase then go back to the installation and see if the drive shows up.

Comment: @MrRabbit Your comment with this link might make for a fabulous answer - http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11068 - explaining that the internal drive is now functionally equivalent to an external needing some basic reconfiguration due to the erasure method.

Comment: What kind of magnet did you use?  You need a really, really strong magnet close to the platters to make a change.  Your average magnet people might have at home isn't going to do a thing.

Answer (score 1):

The HDD work using a magnetic head to read and write,.

The disk it self is coated with magnetic material. So your Magnet has changed the information stored (damage), but possibly not permanent.

So your best choice it to completely reformat the disk, then install a OS.